# Integral, Measurable Functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Assume $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of measurable functions on $[0,
1]$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \int\limits_0^1 |f_n|=0$. Assume there is an integrable function $g$ on $[0,1]$ such that $|f_n|^2\leq g$ for all $n$. Show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \int\limits_0^1 |f_n|^2=0$.

Since the limit of the first integral is $0$, after some $n_0$ the functions $f_n$'s must be integrable. Then i tried to use Dominated Convergence Theorem and put the limit of the second integral inside the integral but couldn't continue with it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a.s convergence to apply the dominated convergence. Your condition
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}|f_n|=0$$
assures that there exists a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ of $f_n$ that converges a.s to $0$. Indeed, observe that the above integral convergence implies that $f_n$ converges to $0$ in $L_1([0,1])$. Hence, we know that there is a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ that converges almost surely to $0$. Now if
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}|f_n|^2 \neq 0$$
There is a subsequence say $f_{n_k}$ of $f$ and $\epsilon>0$ such that
$$\tag{1} \int_{0}^{1}|f_{n_k}|^2\geq \epsilon$$
for every $k$. From the discussion above, we can extract a further subsequence of $f_{n_k}$ that converges a.s to $0$. Denote the subsequence of $f_{n_k}$ that converges a.s to $0$ again by $f_{n_k}$ for simplicity. Then, $|f_{n_k}|^2\leq g$ and $|f_{n_k}|^2\to 0$ a.s combined with the dominated convergence implies
$$\lim_{k\to \infty}\int_{0}^1|f_{n_k}|^2=0$$
which of course contradicts $(1)$.